# How do I get my leafs to hang off my branch correctly using particles?

Tags: particles

I am using particles on my branch to get a few leaves on there. It looks like this when I do it:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

I messed around with the rotation, put the origin to the bottom of the leaf, and I haven't found a way to achieve this.

Comment: pls provide blend file. Check whether you have applied scale + rotation

Comment: the file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/oVvdLJj2. all tranforms are applied

Comment: I would suggest you watch a real tutorial on making plants... this video doesn't explain anything about how you get the leaves onto the stem, no wonder you have a hard time figuring it out. It says "Creating Low-poly Plants", but most of the models are already completely created, they are just rearranged a bit in the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the origin to the position where the particle object is supposed to stick to the emetter:

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot